# Custom XPATH to click checkbox element

Tags: java, react-native, selenium

Hope someone can guide me in the right direction of clicking the 'Active' checkbox ,
Problem is application defaults to have Active checked so filter dropdown stores the option 'Active' so my xpath sees two 'Active' and clicks the first one which is the dropdown.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Active')]")).click();
```

[Screenshot of App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX8Lj.png)

[HTML pic of the dropdown breakdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JKZT.png)

When I used code above two elements were present at the same time so dropdown got clicked instead of actually uncheck the 'Active' checkbox. Hope this makes it clear for you.

Comment: and which one you want to click ?

Comment: Can you please include the relevant part of the HTML so that someone with similar problem can find your question easily? Thanks.

Comment: I will edit the post and update the pic that holds the html part of the dropdown .

Answer (score 0):

When the text is not unique you can add something that makes the xpath unique - some parent or descendant element or more attributes of the wanted element.

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='ant-checkbox-wrapper']//span[contains(text(),'Active')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is present twice, then using `xpath` indexing you can differentiate :

```
(//span[contains(text(),'Active')])[1]
```

or

```
(//span[contains(text(),'Active')])[2]
```

Comment: XPath with indexes are not among the best practices when using Selenium.

Comment: @DebanjanB :  Yes I know, but there wasn't enough HTML shared by OP so that we can distinguish between 2 nodes.

Comment: Won't deny that, however there is a lot of difference between the 2 texts **Active** and **Inactive**

Comment: I still fail to understand, `//span[text()='Active']` is present 1/2 in HTML DOM, and we do not want first element, and we do not have sufficient HTML, so what would be the best way to give answer. Also I got a feedback from `Johan Lindstrom` that it worked great !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of partial text match using *contains()* you can use the exact text match and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Active*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Active']")).click();
  ```
- *Inactive*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Inactive']")).click();
  ```

---

However, as the element is a [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) element so to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Active*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Active']"))).click();
  ```
- *Inactive*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Inactive']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: How does this answer the question ? There are two active web element on the UI. Read carefully.

Comment: @cruisepandey I don't understand your comment/question. Yes, two active web elements, so can you rephrase your question about what you are asking?

Comment: You are using `//span[text()='Active']` and there are 2 web elements with this xpath, and eventually the first web element OP does not want it, so I had a question, how does it help ?

Comment: @cruisepandey There was a typo in the second part of the answer which I have fixed and should address your concern.

Answer (score 0):

if it more than one element found, always you are finding it in same position. better we should do
for eg: following example pointing to 2nd position.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
By appct = By.xpath("//span[text()='Active']");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(appct));
driver.findElements(appct).get(1).click();
System.out.println("Clicked the accept checkbox");
```